# Get certificate authority role service of ADCS server

Tags: certificate, pki

How can we know which Role Services were selected  in the wizard of the ADCS server has configured first time using any cmdlet or command line as like i.e. certutil ?

[ ] Certification Authority : used to issue certificates to users, computers, and services, and to manage certificate validity.

[ ] Certificate Enrollment Policy Web Service : allows users and computers to retrieve information about their certificate enrollment policy.

[ ] Certificate Enrollment Web Service : allows external clients who are not part of the domain network to connect to a CA via Web browser to request certificates.

[ ] Network Device Enrollment Service : allows routers and other network devices that do not have domain accounts to obtain certificates.

[ ] Online Responder : receives and processes requests on the status of the certificates and sends back signed responses containing requested certificate status information.

[image]

Comment: What has this question to do with programming?  It would be better on Server Fault or Super User.

Answer (score 0):

Use PowerShell:

```
Get-WindowsFeature -Name ADCS*

Display Name                                            Name                       Install State
------------                                            ----                       -------------
    [X] Certification Authority                         ADCS-Cert-Authority            Installed
    [ ] Certificate Enrollment Policy Web Service       ADCS-Enroll-Web-Pol            Available
    [ ] Certificate Enrollment Web Service              ADCS-Enroll-Web-Svc            Available
    [ ] Certification Authority Web Enrollment          ADCS-Web-Enrollment            Available
    [ ] Network Device Enrollment Service               ADCS-Device-Enrollment         Available
    [ ] Online Responder                                ADCS-Online-Cert               Available
```

The above shows that the Certification Authority role was installed.